# Crontab in Mac is not working

Tags: cron, macintosh, scheduling

I'm trying to automate a python job using crontab in mac. It's not running on the cron however it's working when run manually & have given full permission to the scripts. As a test, did a echo command which is working as expected. Please help.

```
admin$ crontab -l
  */1 * * * * python3 /Users/admin/Desktop/Py_examples/tweepy_test.py >> /Users/admin/Desktop/Py_examples/log.txt
   */1 * * * * echo 'testing' >> 
     /Users/admin/Desktop/Py_examples/test.txt
```

Comment: Try also keeping the script's stderr in a file: `2>>/Users/admin/Desktop/Py_examples/error.txt`, and then see what appears in this file.

Comment: Is `python3` in your `PATH`? Is it in the `PATH` cron uses? Does `cron` send you emails about errors? Does it work if you use the full path of `python3` in the crontab instead?

Comment: Try the full path to `python3` (or make the script executable with `#!`.

Comment: thanks all for your response. Its working now after python3 absolute path is specified